# Validation on special codes

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a special ID in the format of A000000004..A000000150 etc and OD000000001..OD000000150. I have read the forums here and tried out the solutions (many in the form of `/^([A]{1}\[0-9]{9})$/` etc.) but none of them have helped.

Comment: Thank you Ian. Should I declare /^([A]{1}\[0-9]{9})$/ as a variable and then compare it (!=) with the form feild by taking it also into a variable ?

Comment: var a1=document.forms["addcomplaint"]["accId"].value;
  var a2=/^([A]{1}\[0-9]{9})$/;
  if(a1!=a2){
   alert("Please enter a valid Account ID ex.(A000000004)");
   return false;}
   else return true;

Comment: lol , he just edited your question to make it more readable.. It is not answer to your question. :D

Comment: So can I expect an answer ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your question properly, but how about this regex?

```
/^(A|OD)[0-9]{9}$/
```

To check a string against this regex, you'd use something like this:

```
var regex = /^(A|OD)[0-9]{9}$/;
if (regex.test(myCode)) {
    // ... do something ...
}
```

Comment: Jake it is giving proper validations for all wrong cases AS WELL AS the right sequence/ID . I have posted my code above. Declaring the regex as variable and then comparing it with the form element.

Comment: @NKoder You can't just use `!=` with regexes. I've updated my answer to make it more clear how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

***So the final solution to my question for people who will refer in future:
The code will be:

```
var regex= /^(A|OD)[0-9]{9}$/;
var myCode=document.forms["formname"]["fieldname"].value;
if(!regex.test(myCode))
{
alert(...);
return false;
}
```